# What are `Desktop DB` or `Desktop DF` files on external HD?

Tags: external-hard-drive, hfs+, mac-os-classic

I have two unknown files called `Desktop DB` and `Desktop DF` at the root of an external HD.

The drive is formatted HFS+ and as far as I can remember has only ever been connected to a few Macs.

Both files are binary so I cannot really read them very easily.  But if I `less` them i see some text referring to Adobe Photoshop and image sizes.

What are these files?  Is it OK to delete them ?

Comment: @slhck Are you sure about that retagging, given the answer?

Comment: @DanielBeck Whoops, sorry. Thanks for watching out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are hidden files created & used by Mac OS 6 to 9 (so pre-Mac OS X, if I understand correctly).  See [Apple's KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA46427) and your favourite search engine for more info.